# Copy column (vertical) selection to reverse paste row (horizontal)

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking to transpose column data into Row (one after another).

I have used below code but as data have blank space it is not working.

```
Sub RUN_MACRO()

Range("A1").Select
Selection.End(xlUp).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select

Selection.Copy
Range("J2").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
    False, Transpose:=True
 Range("A6").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
Range("J3").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
    False, Transpose:=True
Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

Below are the screenshots of the input and output.

**Input Data**
[image: Input Data]

**Looking for below Output:**
[image]

Comment: Adding more information: Every input data set have 1 line of blank space.

Comment: Pls can you show us what you came up with so far? And while you do that, please let us know what part isn't working for you so we can assist/advise. If you have done nothing at all, then start with a good search. Plenty of examples out there! [ask]

Comment: Sub RUN_MACRO()

Range("A1").Select
    Selection.End(xlUp).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
   
    Selection.Copy
    Range("J2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=True
    
    
    
    Range("A6").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("J3").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=True
    Range("A1").Select
  
End Sub

Comment: I created above code but it not taking dynamically value of column due to blank space...

Comment: Pls edit your question, see [ask] for some guidelines.

Comment: Question edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work even if there is no data in one of your fields or if you accidentally leave more spaces.

```
Sub test3()

Dim rng As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set rng = Columns("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    For i = 1 To rng.Areas.Count
        rng.Areas(i).Copy
        Range("C" & i + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll, Transpose:=True
    Next i
Set rng = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the sheet containing the data is called Sheet1, since you are not providing a lot of useful information.

```
Sub TransposeData()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Set ws1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")

Dim DataRange As Range
Dim DataCell As Range
Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer
Dim LastRow As Long
x = 0
y = 0

With ws1
LastRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=.Range("A1"), LookAt:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).Row
End With

Set DataRange = ws1.Range("A1:A" & LastRow)
For Each DataCell In DataRange
    If DataCell.Value <> "" Then
        ws1.Range("C2").Offset(y, x).Value = DataCell.Value
        x = x + 1
        If x = 4 Then
            x = 0
            y = y + 1
        End If
    End If
Next DataCell

End Sub
```

This should do the trick. Edited for dynamic operations.

Comment: @AmitRai See the edit, should now work for dynamic ranges as well.

Comment: Its also working, great job... I am working from my end on input data set range if more than 4 .. 5 or 6 column set ...

Comment: @AmitRai shouldn't be to hard to code that in yourself, just tweak the example I made a bit. Glad its working for you :) Don't forget to accept and vote the answer to indicate that your problem was solved ^^.

Comment: My reputation is low, minimum is 15, not able to mark as solved. Any other way plz suggest. I will do.

Comment: @AmitRai You can still accept it. For voting you need 15, so you'll have to gain more rep. Accepting answers to your own posted questions is always possible. https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-posts

Comment: Let me see where it is - accepting answer, great done bro.

Comment: @AmitRai You got it, even got your reputation up to 15 ^^

Comment: @Yellow This will give wrong results if any of the field is left blank.

Comment: @ImranMalek thats true. The code is based on OP's dataset provided, so should work for their needs. The code could however be easily adjusted to run after a certain amount lines to skip the blank lines. Best practice imo would be to not enter blank cells when missing information, only when spacing entries. Instead enter something like "N.A" when information is missing, then no problem will occur.